# C# Reactive Extensions (rx) FirstOrDefault enumerates entire collection

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, rx-java, lazy-evaluation

It seems that the expected behavior of FirstOrDefault is to complete after finding an item that matches the predicate and the expected behavior of concat is to evaluate lazily. However, the following example enumerates the entire collection even though the predicate matches the first item.

(Thanks for the friendlier code Shlomo)

```
void Main()
{
    var entities = Observable.Defer(() => GetObservable().Concat());
    Entity result = null;
    var first = entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.RowId == 1).Subscribe(i => result = i);
    result.Dump();
    buildCalled.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public IEnumerable<IObservable<Entity>> GetObservable()
{
    var rows = new List<EntityTableRow>
    {
        new EntityTableRow { Id = 1, StringVal = "One"},
        new EntityTableRow { Id = 2, StringVal = "Two"},
    };
    return rows.Select(i => Observable.Return(BuildEntity(i)));
}

public int buildCalled = 0;
public Entity BuildEntity(EntityTableRow entityRow)
{
    buildCalled++;
    return new Entity { RowId = entityRow.Id, StringVal = entityRow.StringVal };
}

public class Entity
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string StringVal { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTableRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringVal { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to defer the enumeration of the objects (specifically the building in this case) until truly needed?

Comment: Can you please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is Linqpad-friendly code equivalent to what you have:

```
void Main()
{
    var entities = Observable.Defer(() => GetObservable().Concat());
    Entity result = null;
    var first = entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.RowId == 1).Subscribe(i => result = i);
    result.Dump();
    buildCalled.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public IEnumerable<IObservable<Entity>> GetObservable()
{
    var rows = new List<EntityTableRow>
    {
        new EntityTableRow { Id = 1, StringVal = "One"},
        new EntityTableRow { Id = 2, StringVal = "Two"},
    };
    return rows.Select(i => Observable.Return(BuildEntity(i)));
}

public int buildCalled = 0;
public Entity BuildEntity(EntityTableRow entityRow)
{
    buildCalled++;
    return new Entity { RowId = entityRow.Id, StringVal = entityRow.StringVal };
}

public class Entity
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string StringVal { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTableRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringVal { get; set; }
}
```

If you change `GetObservable` to the following, you'll get the desired result:

```
public IObservable<IObservable<Entity>> GetObservable()
{
    var rows = new List<EntityTableRow>
    {
        new EntityTableRow { Id = 1, StringVal = "One"},
        new EntityTableRow { Id = 2, StringVal = "Two"},
    };
    return rows.ToObservable().Select(i => Observable.Return(BuildEntity(i)));
}
```

It appears the implementation of `Concat<TSource>(IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>>)` is eager in evaluating the enumerable, whereas the implementation of `Concat<TSource>(IObservable<IObservable<TSource>>)` and `ToObservable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` maintain laziness appropriately. I can't say I know why.

Comment: Converting the IEnumerable to an IObservable did indeed stop the eager loading. There doesn't seem to be any documentation describing the difference in behavior; I created an [issue on their repo](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/267) with a reference to this post. Thanks for the help Shlomo

Comment: @kmusick - This is why we don't let friends mix monads. Don't mix `IEnumerable<T>` and `IObservable<T>` if you can avoid it. Your `GetObservable` method should have simply returned `IObservable<Entity>` and the `return` should be `return rows.ToObservable().Select(i => BuildEntity(i));`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Amen.

Comment: ++@Enigmativity. All the OP needed was a bunch of entities. An observable of entities would have sufficed. I think the OP unnecessarily complicates the issue.